# How to loop a dynamic range and copy select information within that range to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, dynamic, range

I have already created a VBA script that is about 160 lines long, which produces the report that you see below.

Without using cell references (because the date ranges will change each time I run this) I now need to take the users ID, name, total hours, total break, overtime 1, and overtime 2 and copy this data into sheet 2.

Any suggestions as to how I can structure a VBA script to search row B until a blank is found, when a blank is found, copy the values from column J, K, L, M on that row, and on the row above copy value C - now paste these values on sheet 2. - Continue this process until you find two consecutive blanks or the end of the data...

Even if you can suggest a different way to tackle this problem than the logic I have assumed above it would be greatly appreciated. I can share the whole code if you are interested and show you the data I began with.

Thank you in advance, 
J

[image: Example]

Comment: By `copy the values from the cell above`, you mean copy the last line from the block of data ***before*** the blank, yes? Like in the above screenshot, copy `C15` and `J15:M15`?

Comment: Please add the code you have and tell us where you are stuck

Comment: @BK201 No, so Copy C15 and J16:M16 in the image

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree I can copy the code I have used to get me to the screenshot above, which will not be helpful. I am looking for the best logic to tackle this final section of my macro.

Comment: I like how you're approaching this, asking for logic instead of the exact code. I'll give you one and it's very nice. Use `AutoFilter` and filter for `Blanks`. You'll end up with the total stats in `J16:M16` for each `Username`. Find a way to hook/associate the `Username` via a loop to the stats. That should work perfectly. :)

Comment: @BK201 - The AutoFilter will not work because the username is in the row above the sum numbers I need... When I filter I get all the sum numbers, but no username. Any thoughts?

Comment: @bk201 - Okay nevermind. Maybe I will try the below for range C to fix this    `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"`

Comment: Which was why I said to find an inventive way to get the username. :) I'll post an answer in a while. Not by a PC yet. :)

Comment: @BK201 - Gotcha - I have the code written now! Thanks.

Comment: Kindly post your code. It will help others. I'll post my approach as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

As discussed, here's my approach. All the details are in the **code's comments** so make sure you read them.

```
Sub GetUserNameTotals()

    Dim ShTarget As Worksheet: Set ShTarget = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ShPaste As Worksheet: Set ShPaste = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim RngTarget As Range: Set RngTarget = ShTarget.UsedRange
    Dim RngTargetVisible As Range, CellRef As Range, ColRef As Range, RngNames As Range
    Dim ColIDIndex As Long: ColIDIndex = Application.Match("ID", RngTarget.Rows(1), 0)
    Dim LRow As Long: LRow = RngTarget.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    'Turn off AutoFilter to avoid errors.
    ShTarget.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Logic: Apply filter on the UserName column, selecting blanks. We then get two essential ranges.
    'RngTargetVisible is the visible range of stats. ColRef is the visible first column of stats.
    With RngTarget
        .AutoFilter Field:=ColIDIndex, Criteria1:="=", Operator:=xlFilterValues, VisibleDropDown:=True
        Set RngTargetVisible = .Range("J2:M" & LRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        Set ColRef = .Range("J2:J" & LRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    End With

    'Logic: For each cell in the first column of stats, let's get its offset one cell above
    'and 7 cells to the left. This method is not necessary. Simply assigning ColRef to Column C's
    'visible cells and changing below to CellRef.Offset(-1,0) is alright. I chose this way so it's
    'easier to visualize the approach. RngNames is a consolidation of the cells with ranges, which we'll
    'copy first before the stats.
    For Each CellRef In ColRef
        If RngNames Is Nothing Then
            Set RngNames = CellRef.Offset(-1, -7)
        Else
            Set RngNames = Union(RngNames, CellRef.Offset(-1, -7))
        End If
    Next CellRef

    'Copy the names first, then RngTargetVisible, which are the total stats. Copying headers is up
    'to you. Of course, modify as necessary.
    RngNames.Copy ShPaste.Range("A1")
    RngTargetVisible.Copy ShPaste.Range("B1")

End Sub
```

### **Screenshots:**

**Set-up:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

**Demo video here:**

[Using Filters and Visible Cells](http://youtu.be/MZO_KFf4Izk?hd=1)

Let us know if this helps.